# Use of Undeclared Type 'ARConfiguration'

Tags: ios, arkit

I'm trying to run this ARKit demo code: https://github.com/exyte/ARTetris and I keep getting the error "Use of undeclared type 'ARConfiguration'" in my ViewController file.

I've looked through almost every question regarding "use of undeclared type" on stackoverflow and none of them were able to fix my problem.

I've imported UIKit, SceneKit and ARKit and all my Target memberships seem right. Stumped.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20IUn.png)

Answer (score 0):

I cloned the project and it builds fine.

Make sure you are using **xcode9**.

I used **xcode9 beta5**.

Comment: Also downloaded and ran the project. Works fine.